# Why are my height and width calculations incorrect when aligning TikZ Calendar days on a page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar, tikz-calendar

I am trying to put together a dynamically sized calendar for the current year. I just need to specify these things

- width of calendar (set to `\textwidth` for dynamic resizing)
- height of calendar (set to `\textheight` for dynamic resizing)
- how many months per page
- total number of days per month to display (I used 32, 31 max days in month + 1 for month label)

The year is set automatically to the current year.

## Questions

- Why is the total horizontal width of my days (each `\daywd`) not equal to the `\textwidth`?
- Why must I set the `\dayht` to equal only 98% of the `\textheight`?

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} % Adds nodes around page boxes (e.g. body)
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead{Current Year: \the\year}
\rhead{Current Date: \yyyymmdddate\today}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{datetime}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{-}

\def\mntcount{2}% Set month count
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{(\textheight / 32)*.98} % How can I set this to 100% \textheight and still get it on one page?
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\dayht{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathparse{(\textwidth / \mntcount)}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\daywd{\pgfmathresult}

%\count255 = 1
%\loop
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
  \calendar
    [anchor=north west,dates=\the\year-1-01 to 
           \the\year-\mntcount-last,
           every day/.style={baseline=(current bounding box.north west),inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},
           % Slightly modify each day's node
           day code={
             \node [name=\pgfcalendarsuggestedname,shape=rectangle,draw,minimum height=\dayht,minimum width=\daywd,text width=\daywd]
              {\tikzdaytext};
           },
           % Add months
           execute before day scope={
             %\ifdate{day of month=1}{\tikzmonthcode}{},
             %every month/.append style={anchor=north,yshift=2em}
             % Print month name
             \ifdate{day of month=1}
               {
               % Shift right, coordinate system right(first iteration is ok because points are relative)
               \pgftransformxshift{\daywd}
                 \draw (0,0) node [shape=rectangle, draw = red, font=\color{orange},text centered,text width=\daywd]
                 {\pgfcalendarmonthname{\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth}};
               }{}{},every month/.append style={anchor=south,yshift=2cm}
           },
           % Each day is placed at (0,0), so shift entire coordinate system downwards after each day
           %execute after day scope={\pgftransformyshift{-\dayht}}, % Initial Working Attempt
           execute at begin day scope={\pgftransformyshift{-\dayht*\pgfcalendarcurrentday pt}} %
    ] at (current page text area.north west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
% \ifnum\count255 < 12
%   \advance\count255 by 1
%\repeat
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

## TO DO

1. Make Text scale when natural width is above or below a certain threshold based on ratios.
2. No easy interface for multiple languages
3. No easy interface for importing holidays from `.ics`

Comment: @cfr I thought `minimum width` would be redundant here due to `text width`. I just threw it in there in case I wanted to make the text width less than the minimum width someday.

Comment: @cfr If `text width=3cm` and you do a `inner sep=0pt`, then the node is not wider than `text width` I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to account for the width and height of rules and *either* ensure that `inner sep=0pt` is actually *applied* - in your MWE, the `every day` style has no effect at all - *or* stick to `minimum width` as `text width=<x>` will produce a node with width greater than `<x>`.

If you do that, it all fits:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} % Adds nodes around page boxes (e.g. body)
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead{Current Year: \the\year}
\rhead{Current Date: \yyyymmdddate\today}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{datetime}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{-}
\def\mntcount{2}% Set month count
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\dayht{((\textheight-2*\pgflinewidth)/ 32)}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\daywd{(\textwidth / \mntcount)-\pgflinewidth}%
  \calendar
  [anchor=north west,dates=\the\year-1-01 to
  \the\year-\mntcount-last,
  every day/.style={baseline=(current bounding box.north west), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
  % Slightly modify each day's node
  day code={%
    \node [every day, name=\pgfcalendarsuggestedname, draw, align=left, minimum height=\dayht, minimum width=\daywd, text width=\daywd]
    {\tikzdaytext};
  },
  % Add months
  execute before day scope={%
    %\ifdate{day of month=1}{\tikzmonthcode}{},
    %every month/.append style={anchor=north,yshift=2em}
    % Print month name
    \ifdate{day of month=1}
    {%
      % Shift right, coordinate system right(first iteration is ok because points are relative)
      \pgftransformxshift{\daywd}%
      \draw (0,0) node [draw = red, text=orange, minimum height=\dayht, minimum width=\daywd]
      {\pgfcalendarmonthname{\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth}};
    }{}{},
    every month/.append style={anchor=south, yshift=2cm }%
  },
  % Each day is placed at (0,0), so shift entire coordinate system downwards after each day
  %execute after day scope={\pgftransformyshift{-\dayht}}, % Initial Working Attempt
  execute at begin day scope={\pgftransformyshift{-\dayht*\pgfcalendarcurrentday pt}}%
  ] at (current page text area.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: calendar to fit]

## EDIT

This is a follow-up based on looking at the code you posted in your answer in light of the discussion in comments there.

I think you are making life more difficult for yourself than you need to. At least, I don't see why all the `\dd` stuff is required. The following example doesn't handle the language stuff and it lacks a couple of bells and whistles, but it does demonstrate how to produce a 12-month list of days with dates and month headings which is roughly similar to yours, but a bit more straightforward in terms of implementation.

The calendar is based on 2 colours. One is the background colour (`white` by default). The other is the highlight colour used for filling weekend days, labelling months etc. (`gray` by default; `specialred` from your answer in the example).

```
\colorlet{calbkcolour}{white}
\colorlet{calcolour}{gray}
```

We set some keys for use with calendars.

```
\tikzset{%
```

First, we'll use `cal colour` to change the highlight colour and `cal back colour` to change the background colour.

```
  cal colour/.code={%
    \colorlet{calcolour}{#1}%s
  },
  cal back colour/.code={%
    \colorlet{calbkcolour}{#1}%s
  },
```

In your code, you set `inner sep` to `0pt` and then have to compensate explicitly in the content using `\mbox`es. This doesn't seem the simplest solution. We'll use a key to set a consistent, configurable `inner sep` for our calendars so that, like the two colours above, it is always the same within a calendar but can vary between them.

```
  cal inner sep/.store in=\calinnersep,
  cal inner sep=2.5pt,
```

We'll do the same for the number of months.

```
  cal month count/.store in=\calmntcount,
  cal month count=2,
```

Now, we'll set up a key `cal config` to execute some code, when necessary, to do the calculations for us. I'm not sure if this is the ideal solution, but it seems to work reasonably well.

```
  cal config/.code={%
```

First, calculating the height and width of each node, roughly as before.

```
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\caldayht{((\textheight-\pgflinewidth)/ 32)}%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\caldaywd{(\textwidth / \calmntcount)-\pgflinewidth}%
```

We're going to use another length macro for the width of the text within the node. Although we don't need it here, the commented code could be used for the height of the node text, if desired.

```
    %     \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\caldaytxtht{((\textheight-\pgflinewidth)/ 32)-2*\calinnersep}% currently unused
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\caldaytxtwd{(\textwidth / \calmntcount)-\pgflinewidth-2*\calinnersep}%
  },
```

We trigger this code to make sure everything has some default value - just in case.

```
  cal config,
}
```

Now for the `\calendar`. I have to admit I find this macro strange, hard to use and the documentation difficult to understand.

```
  \calendar
  [
    anchor=north west,
    cal month count=12,
```

This needs to come before `cal config`. If you wish to change `cal inner sep` it should be done first, too.

```
    cal colour=specialred,
```

Change the highlight colour from `gray`.

```
    cal config,
```

We need to do this because we've changed the number of months from the default (`2`) to `12`. Otherwise, we could skip it to save the calculation time.

Some of the following could be added to the `cal config` if it will not vary between calendars.

```
    dates=\the\year-1-01 to \the\year-\calmntcount-last,
```

The specialised day code - aside from the stuff to add the month label - was not really doing anything, so drop it and just use the `every day` style.

```
    every day/.style={baseline=(current bounding box.north west), fill=calbkcolour, inner sep=\calinnersep, outer sep=0pt, draw, align=left, minimum height=\caldayht, minimum width=\caldaywd, text width=\caldaytxtwd},
```

The trick here is the `fill=calbkcolour` which will get changed for weekends. Note that `calbkcolour` is a colour name and not a macro, as explained above.

Similarly, we can simplify the month stuff by relying on the `every month` style.

```
    every month/.style={font=\bfseries, text=calcolour, minimum height=\caldayht, inner sep=\calinnersep, minimum width=\caldaywd},
```

Here we're setting the text colour to `calcolour`. Again, it is a colour name rather than a macro. Note, too, `\bfseries`. ***`\bf` and friends have been deprecated for use in LaTeX for 20+ years and ought not be used in new code.***

Here's the simplified `month code`.

```
    month code={%
      \pgftransformxshift{\caldaywd}%
      \node [every month] {\tikzmonthtext};
    },
```

This is the simplified `execute before day scope`.

```
    execute before day scope={%
      % Print month name
      \ifdate{day of month=1}
      {%
        \tikzmonthcode
      }{},
    },
    execute at begin day scope={\pgftransformyshift{-\caldayht*\pgfcalendarcurrentday pt}},
  ]
```

Now for the weekends.

```
  if (Sunday) [cal back colour=calcolour!30]
  if (Saturday) [cal back colour=calcolour!20]
```

Notice that this is setting `calbkcolour` to a mix based on the highlight colour, `calcolour`. This is then effective in the `fill=calbkcolour` in the `every day` style, but will be limited, of course, to the days which satisfy the conditionals.

This strange indirect method is due to the fact that it will not work, for example to say `if (Sunday) [fill=red]` even though it does work to say `if (Sunday) [red]` for red text. The issue has nothing to do with the `at`.

```
  at (current page text area.north west)% note that this makes no difference in this example
```

However, the `at` isn't necessary and could be eliminated. I've just left it in to show it isn't a problem combining it with the conditional formatting, as you'd thought.

```
  ;
```

That's it.

[image: fancier calendar simpler]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[a3paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} % Adds nodes around page boxes (e.g. body)
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\definecolor{specialred}{cmyk}{.07,.81,.59,.04}
\colorlet{calbkcolour}{white}
\colorlet{calcolour}{gray}
\tikzset{%
  cal colour/.code={%
    \colorlet{calcolour}{#1}%s
  },
  cal back colour/.code={%
    \colorlet{calbkcolour}{#1}%s
  },
  cal inner sep/.store in=\calinnersep,
  cal inner sep=2.5pt,
  cal month count/.store in=\calmntcount,
  cal month count=2,
  cal config/.code={%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\caldayht{((\textheight-\pgflinewidth)/ 32)}%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\caldaywd{(\textwidth / \calmntcount)-\pgflinewidth}%
    %     \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\caldaytxtht{((\textheight-\pgflinewidth)/ 32)-2*\calinnersep}% currently unused
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\caldaytxtwd{(\textwidth / \calmntcount)-\pgflinewidth-2*\calinnersep}%
  },
  cal config,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \calendar
  [
    anchor=north west,
    cal month count=12,
    cal colour=specialred,
    cal config,
    dates=\the\year-1-01 to \the\year-\calmntcount-last,
    every day/.style={baseline=(current bounding box.north west), fill=calbkcolour, inner sep=\calinnersep, outer sep=0pt, draw, align=left, minimum height=\caldayht, minimum width=\caldaywd, text width=\caldaytxtwd},
    every month/.style={font=\bfseries, text=calcolour, minimum height=\caldayht, inner sep=\calinnersep, minimum width=\caldaywd},
    month code={%
      \pgftransformxshift{\caldaywd}%
      \node [every month] {\tikzmonthtext};
    },
    execute before day scope={%
      % Print month name
      \ifdate{day of month=1}
      {%
        \tikzmonthcode
      }{},
    },
    execute at begin day scope={\pgftransformyshift{-\caldayht*\pgfcalendarcurrentday pt}},
  ]
  if (Sunday) [cal back colour=calcolour!30]
  if (Saturday) [cal back colour=calcolour!20]
  at (current page text area.north west)% note that this makes no difference in this example
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My only gripe is that you used a fixed value for the rules instead of a variable. That makes the calendar no longer dynamic. (the .4pt and .8pt). Any fix for that in case the rule sizes are different than default?

Comment: It is just a minimal example. You can use the current line width or a variable or whatever. `.4pt` is just the standard line width so I used it for example.

Comment: Yea I was asking where .4pt and .8pt are set.

Comment: That's just the default and twice the default.

Comment: I just noticed that the days align center now with the removal of `text width`. This is undesired.

Comment: The problem with `text width` was that you weren't applying `every day` to the nodes creating the days. So the `inner sep` was added on.

Comment: I am glad you found the real culprit. My unclean solution was `text width=\daywd-8` (unit  pt by default)

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I missed it before. I'm not very familiar with the high-level calendar stuff, although I know the lower level stuff a bit better.

Comment: I am jealous ;)

Comment: I've been using it to make `chronos`, which is something I've been using to answer questions about timelines, especially the ones using `chronosys` (which is awful) and `chronology` (which is a bit limited).

Answer (score 6):

In case anybody is interested, here is my code after some touching up. I work with minority languages, so it is both useful and fun to be able to customize calendars like this.

## Create a language file

Ideally you'd create a langauge switcher function that sets variables like language code, native language name, etc. For a quick and dirty solution, just hardcode everything like I did here:

### Welsh

```
% Setup Month Names
\def\pgfcalendarmonthname#1{%
  \translate{\ifcase#1\or Ionawr\or Chwefror\or Mawrth\or Ebrill\or
    Mai\or Mehefin\or Gorffennaf\or Awst\or Medi\or Hydref\or
    Tachwedd\or Rhagfyr\fi}%
}
% Setup Weekday Short Names
\def\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname#1{%
\translate{\ifcase#1 Ll.\or Ma.\or Me.\or
Ia.\or Gw.\or Sa. \or Su.\fi}}
```

### Upland Tyrolean

```
% Setup Month Names
\def\pgfcalendarmonthname#1{%
  \translate{\ifcase#1\or Jänner\or Feber\or März\or April\or
    Mai\or Juni\or Juli\or August\or September\or Oktober\or
    November\or Dezember\fi}%
}
% Setup Weekday Short Names
\def\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname#1{%
\translate{\ifcase#1 Ma.\or Eh.\or Mi.\or
Do.\or Fr.\or Sa. \or Su.\fi}}
```

## Calendar File vertical_serialized_days_per_month_calendar.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Liberation Sans}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=5mm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} % Adds nodes around page boxes (e.g. body)
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,calc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{3pt}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{%
  \color{\calcolor}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}
\lhead{\Huge\textcolor{\calcolor}{\the\year}}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{Komar © \yyyymmdddate\today}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{Tiroler Oberland}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{datetime}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{-}

\definecolor{specialred}{cmyk}{.07,.81,.59,.04}
\def\calcolor{specialred}
\def\mntcount{12}% Set month count
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% Setup Month Names
% Setup Weekday Short Names
%\input{welsh.tex}
%\input{oberland_tirolerisch.tex}
\def\pgfcalendarmonthname#1{%
  \translate{\ifcase#1\or Jänner\or Feber\or März\or April\or
    Mai\or Juni\or Juli\or August\or September\or Oktober\or
    November\or Dezember\fi}%
}
% Setup Weekday Short Names
\def\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname#1{%
\translate{\ifcase#1 Ma.\or Eh.\or Mi.\or
Do.\or Fr.\or Sa. \or Su.\fi}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\dayht{((\textheight-2*\pgflinewidth)/ 32)}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\daywd{(\textwidth / \mntcount)-\pgflinewidth}%
  \calendar
  [anchor=north west,dates=\the\year-1-01 to
  \the\year-\mntcount-last,
  every day/.style={baseline=(current bounding box.north west), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
  % Slightly modify each day's node
  day code={%
    \def\dddescription{}%default description
    \def\ddcolor{white}%default day color
    \ifdate {Sunday}
      {%
      \def\dddescription{}
      \def\ddcolor{\calcolor!30}
      }%true
      {}%false
    \ifdate {Saturday}
      {%
      \def\dddescription{}
      \def\ddcolor{\calcolor!20}
      }%true
      {}%false
    \ifdate {workday}
      {%
      \def\dddescription{}
      \def\ddcolor{white}
      }%true
      {}%false
    % Generated with script
    \ifdate{equals=2016-01-01}{\def\dddescription{Neujahr}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2016-01-06}{\def\dddescription{Heilige Drei Könige}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2016-03-19}{\def\dddescription{St. Josef}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2016-05-01}{\def\dddescription{Staatsfeiertag}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2016-05-04}{\def\dddescription{St. Florian}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2016-08-15}{\def\dddescription{Mariä Himmelfahrt}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2016-09-24}{\def\dddescription{St. Rupert}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2016-10-10}{\def\dddescription{Tag der Volksabstimmung}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2016-10-26}{\def\dddescription{Nationalfeiertag}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2016-11-01}{\def\dddescription{Allerheiligen}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2016-11-11}{\def\dddescription{St. Martin}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2016-11-15}{\def\dddescription{St. Leopold}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2016-12-08}{\def\dddescription{Mariä Empfängnis}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2016-12-24}{\def\dddescription{Heiliger Abend}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2016-12-25}{\def\dddescription{Weihnachten}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2016-12-26}{\def\dddescription{Stefanitag}}{}
    \ifdate{equals=2016-12-31}{\def\dddescription{Silvester}}{}
    \node [%
      every day,
      name=\pgfcalendarsuggestedname,
      draw,
      fill=\ddcolor,
      align=left,
      minimum height=\dayht,
      minimum width=\daywd,
      text width=\daywd
    ]%
    (\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth-\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday)%unique label format mm-dd
    {\mbox{ }\tikzdaytext\mbox{ }{\tiny\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}}};
    \node [anchor=south east,font=\fontsize{3}{4}\selectfont,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at ($(\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth-\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday.south east)+(-.2ex,.2ex)$) {\dddescription};
  },
  % Add months
  execute before day scope={%
    %\ifdate{day of month=1}{\tikzmonthcode}{},
    %every month/.append style={anchor=north,yshift=2em}
    % Print month name
    \ifdate{day of month=1}
    {%
      % Shift right, coordinate system right(first iteration is ok because points are relative)
      \pgftransformxshift{\daywd}%
      \draw (0,0) node [text=\calcolor, font=\bf,minimum height=\dayht, minimum width=\daywd]
      {\pgfcalendarmonthname{\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth}};
    }{}{},
  },
  % Each day is placed at (0,0), so shift entire coordinate system downwards after each day
  %execute after day scope={\pgftransformyshift{-\dayht}}, % Initial Working Attempt
  execute at begin day scope={\pgftransformyshift{-\dayht*\pgfcalendarcurrentday pt}}%
  ] at (current page text area.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Upland Tyrolean

Updated to include holidays from .ics file. I will add a link to my script in the future.
[image]

## Welsh

[image]

---

## Notes

As reference from `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarycalendar.code.tex`

*line 86 contains the important day code node default definition*

```
 71 % Templates for typesetting days, month, years
 72
 73 \tikzoption{day code}{\def\tikzdaycode{#1}}
 74 \tikzoption{day text}{\def\tikzdaytext{#1}}
 75 \tikzoption{days}{\tikzstyle{every day}+=[#1]}
 76 \tikzstyle{every day}=[anchor=base east]
 77
 78 \tikzoption{month code}{\def\tikzmonthcode{#1}}
 79 \tikzoption{month text}{\def\tikzmonthtext{#1}}
 80 \tikzstyle{every month}=[]
 81
 82 \tikzoption{year code}{\def\tikzyearcode{#1}}
 83 \tikzoption{year text}{\def\tikzyeartext{#1}}
 84 \tikzstyle{every year}=[]
 85
 86 \def\tikzdaycode{\node[name=\pgfcalendarsuggestedname,every day]{\tikzdaytext};}
 87 \def\tikzmonthcode{\node[every month]{\tikzmonthtext};}
 88 \def\tikzyearcode{\node[every year]{\tikzyeartext};}
 89
 90 \def\tikzdaytext{\%d-}
 91 \def\tikzmonthtext{\%mt}
 92 \def\tikzyeartext{\%y0}
```

I could significantly increase typesetting time and reduce memory by including the coloring logic in the `day code` like this:

```
  day code={%
    \def\dddescription{}%default description
    \def\ddcolor{white}%default day color
    \ifdate {Sunday}
      {%
      \def\dddescription{Sunday}
      \def\ddcolor{\calcolor!30}
      }%true
      {}%false
    \ifdate {Saturday}
      {%
      \def\dddescription{Saturday}
      \def\ddcolor{\calcolor!20}
      }%true
      {}%false
     \ifdate {workday}
      {%
      \def\dddescription{Workday}
      \def\ddcolor{white}
      }%true
      {}%false
     \node [%
       every day, 
       name=\pgfcalendarsuggestedname, 
       draw, 
       fill=\ddcolor,
       align=left, 
       minimum height=\dayht, 
       minimum width=\daywd, 
       text width=\daywd
       ]%
       {\space\tikzdaytext\space{\tiny\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}\dddescription}};
  },
```

Comment: Can you do one for Welsh? ;)

Comment: @cfr Done. Do you know why so much memory is needed for the coloring of days? Is there a cleverer way of setting up day coloring logic?

Comment: Oh, wow! I was only joking, really. That's neat. Thank you! I have no idea about the memory. What are you going by exactly? Do you mean the message about how much memory TeX used goes up when you add the colour?

Comment: The abbreviation for Monday should really be `Llu.` to match the others, but that's a minor quibble ;). (`ll` is one letter.)

Comment: @cfr I mean if you comment out the ifday is saturday etc, compilation time is much faster. I think pgf is coloring all days per rule. Each rule overwrites the other. So 360 color applications per coditional rule. There must be a way to abstract the logic from the coloring. Haha no prob. Thanks for catching the ll.

Comment: Is the `if (Sunday) [fill=<colour>] else ... ` syntax faster? That seems to be what the examples do. You seem to be doing the setup separately for every day of the calendar. (That said, TikZ can be extremely slow. Or else I just don't know the best tricks.)

Comment: @cfr That might be it, but I must be missing another parameter from my `day code`, because adding a statement like `\calendar[...] at (current page text area.north west) if (Sunday) [fill=red] ;` has no effect.

Comment: Can you put the `at` after the `if`? Note that I'm guessing here ... I can try to look later.

Comment: Please see my edited answer. I don't think you need all the `\dd` stuff. Although I've not added every bell and whistle from this, I do think you can simplify this quite a lot and I've tried to illustrate some ways to do that.